what does this mean? $e^{\begin{bmatrix}x&y\end{bmatrix}}$
I was plotting random things on Desmos when i tried this graph.
i tried putting the matrix
$\begin{bmatrix}
x & y 
\end{bmatrix}$
to the power of $e$.
this is what im trying to say:
$e^{\begin{bmatrix}x&y\end{bmatrix}}$
while i expected it to do something crazy, it just plotted $e^{xy}$, i thought that maybe Desmos doesn't recognises matrices but i wasn't quite sure.
can anybody explain what  $e^{\begin{bmatrix}x&y\end{bmatrix}}$ would really mean,so that i know that i am not just expecting some complex stuff out of it.

try using the power series definition of e^x := 1 + x + x²/2! + x³/3! + ... plugging in elements from a ring other than the reals generally gives interesting results

When $A$ is a square matrix, $e^A$ is defined by the usual power series. But this isn't a square matrix. The best way of find out if Desmos supports,Patrices, and what syntax to use if they do, is best answered in Desmos documentation. But it seems to interpret the square brackets as parentheses, so $[x y]$ is the same as $(xy).$

e^[x y]= y=(e^x)+ (e^y) = y. 3blue1brown made an interesting video on this topic.https://youtu.be/O85OWBJ2ayo?si=dVXt9ZSQ2oPFh_GC

@ThomasAndrews is my question even valid?

Probably it takes the vector as a "successive exponentiation" like $e^{[a,b,c,\dots]} = (((e^a)^b)^c)^{\dots}$. Try with $e^{[2,3,4]}$ and check if it is equal to $e^{24}$

@Exodd it doesn't take it as repeated exponentiation take a look

Ok, it seems it just puts the digits together: $2^{[1\ 0 \ 0]}$ is the same as $2^{100}$
